# Web Services call - core_group_create_groups - Unexpected keys (courseid) detected in parameter array

Tags: moodle

I'm having an issue with a specific Rest webservice call :

Method: `core_group_create_groups`

Is throwing the following error:

> Unexpected keys (courseid) detected in parameter array.

I'm passing in the exact properties defined in the documentation:

```
_ //List of group object. A group has a courseid, a name, a description and an enrolment key.
list of ( 
    object {
        courseid int   //id of course
        name string   //multilang compatible name, course unique
        description string   //group description text
        descriptionformat int  Default to "1" //description format (1 = HTML, 0 = MOODLE, 2 = PLAIN or 4 = MARKDOWN)
        enrolmentkey string  Optional //group enrol secret phrase
        idnumber string  Optional //id number
    } 
)_
```

I'm using Moodle 3.1+ (Build: 20160623)

Any ideas why it doesn't like `courseid` in the request even though its a valid parameter?

Answer (score 1):

having problems here with Moodle documentation too. 
parameters marked as optional in docs actually are required.

example: 
in the method 'core_role_assign_roles' you MUST pass 'contextlevel' and 'instanceid', the doc say is optional.

I just used the 'core_group_create_groups' method and it worked fine. this time the docs were correct passed 3 params: courseid / name / description.

used like:

```
"groups[0][courseid]=2&groups[0][name]=grupo2&groups[0][description]=desc grupo2"
```

maybe double check if the code you are passing in courseid a) exists; b) is really a course id.

hope it helps,
rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the webservice using the "groups" key to make it works correctly (i.e. this code works for me in PHP):

```
`$this->callWSFunction(
'core_group_create_groups',[
            groups =>[ 
                0 => 
                    [
                        'courseid' => $id,
                        'name' => $groupname,
                        'description' => $groupdescription
                     ]
                 ]
            ]
         );`
```